# Change react-text value with external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, discord

I am making a plugin for the app Discord.
I want to change the react-text values where it says "and" and "are typing..." as shown in the code below.

```
<span class="text">
    <strong>
        <!-- react-text: 191441 -->user1<!-- /react-text -->
    </strong>
        <!-- react-text: 191442 --> and <!-- /react-text -->
    <strong>
        <!-- react-text: 191450 -->user2<!-- /react-text -->
    </strong>
    <!-- react-text: 191451 --> are typing...<!-- /react-text -->
</span>
```

Would this be possible to do with an external JavaScript file?

Comment: I am guessing the code snip is copied from the browser? If you can get access to the React component this is generated from the change would be trivial. If I understand your question correctly though, you can't?

Comment: Yes, this is from the source code of the app I'm making the plugin for.  
Since I am only making a plugin I can only modify the current scripts via an external script. I just need to figure how to edit the React elements.

Comment: Are there any less generic class names or ids on the containing html elements? I ask as selecting by class is prone to picking up a lot of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This should work given the code you posted. If you have multiple occurrences of this snippet you would want to run this the `replacer` function inside a loop. Just make sure that the replacer function gets called after React has update the DOM with this snippet.

```
var replacer = function replacer() {
  var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerHTML.replace('and', 'or');

  document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerHTML = selector
}
replacer()
```

[Here is a bin with it running.](https://jsbin.com/qoyobexixa/edit?html,js,output)